# Kafka to postgres without kafka connectors

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to downstream data from kafka topics to a relational db like postgres. I don't want to use kafka connect or jdbc connectors. Is their any way I can use raw queries to export data from kafka to postgres.

I will be using python to implement this

Comment: You can, sure. What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: I do not know how to do that. Should I use kSQL to query data and then insert it manually in postgres?

Comment: Your question asked nothing about querying, only using python, Kafka, and Postgres. You consume a topic, parse fields out, and write to a table... Kafka Connect comes with Kafka, so it's not really clear why you wouldn't use it

Comment: I am trying to learn to do it without kafka connect. Do I just parse the event in consumer and use an insert query for postgres?

Comment: That's correct. But you also need to handle offset commits, consumer group coordination, restarts, bad data, and any potential table column modification